# ¿ejecutar una funcion propia una sola vez jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Tengo esta función,

```
    function llenarcombos() {
        $.post("/Oficina/OficinaGeneral",
          function (data) {
              $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                  $('#Ecbooficinageneral').append('<option value="' + item.Cod_Oficina_G + '">' + item.Nom_OFicina_G + '</option>');
                  $("#Ecbooficinageneral").val(DepOficina);
                  $('#Ecbooficinageneral').change();
              });
          });

        $.post("/Oficina/OficinaDep",
            { codofi: CodOficina },
            function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    $('#Ecbooficinadep').append('<option value="' + item.Cod_Oficina_D + '">' + item.Nom_Oficina_D + '</option');
                    $("#Ecbooficinadep").val(CodOficina);
                    $('#Ecbooficinadep').change();
                });
            });
        };
```

lo quiero ejecutar una sola vez con llenarcombos().one();

ya que despues de esto hare el llenado de combox uno dependiendo del otro con esto:

```
$.post("/Oficina/OficinaGeneral",
     function (data) {
         $.each(data, function (i, item) {
             $('#Ecbooficinageneral').append('<option value="' + item.Cod_Oficina_G + '">' + item.Nom_OFicina_G + '</option>');
         });
     });

    $('#Ecbooficinageneral').change(function () {
        $('#Ecbooficinageneral').each(function () {
            var codofi = $('#Ecbooficinageneral').val();
            $('#Ecbooficinadep').val(null).trigger('change');
            $('#Ecbooficinadep').html('<select class="form-control select2" id="cbooficinadep" style="width: 100%;">' +
                                    '<option selected="selected" value="">Seleccione Oficina Dependiente</option>' +
                                    '</select>');
            $.post("/Oficina/OficinaDep",
                { codofi: codofi },
                function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $('#Ecbooficinadep').append('<option value="' + item.Cod_Oficina_D + '">' + item.Nom_Oficina_D + '</option');
                    });
                });
        });
    });
```

la primera llena los combos para poder editarlos lo segundo hace que se cargue dependiendo del de la primera seleccion del select2,

si hago el llenado solo con dando el valor .val .change como la primera, el segundo select se llena tanta veces como se repita el primero, queria evitar eso

los datos que se toman es por un onclick de un boton editar donde toma todo los datos de un datatable.net

EditarTrabajador = function (TipDocumento, N_Documento, NomTrabajador, PatTrabajador, MatTrabajador, CodOficina, NomOficina, DepOficina, CodUbigeo, TipTrabajador, DesCampo) {...codigo mendionado anteriormente...}

Comment: y en que momento quieres que se ejecute ?

Comment: La manera de ejecutarla una vez es simplemente llamarla: `llenarcombos();`. ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir realmente?

Comment: se ejecuta al hacer clik en un boton editar, este hace la carga de todo los selects desde la bd, por eso dije automanticamente.

Comment: quieres que solo se ejecute cuando la pagina cargue ?

Comment: Sólo mandala a llamar una vez, no necesitas hacer otra cosa.

Answer (score 5):

Creo que lo que buscas es

```
$('#idBoton').one('click',llenarcombos);
```

Con lo que sólo la primera vez que pulses el botón funcionará, después de eso jQuery eliminará el *listener* del botón.

Answer (score 0):

pones el boton a la escucha para que cuando sea presionado ejecute la funcion ejemplo...

con el Id del boton capturas el evento y asi desencadenas lo que deseas..

```
$("#id_boton").click(function(){
    $.post("/Oficina/OficinaGeneral",
      function (data) {
          $.each(data, function (i, item) {
              $('#Ecbooficinageneral').append('<option value="' + item.Cod_Oficina_G + '">' + item.Nom_OFicina_G + '</option>');
              $("#Ecbooficinageneral").val(DepOficina);
              $('#Ecbooficinageneral').change();
          });
      });

    $.post("/Oficina/OficinaDep",
    { codofi: CodOficina },
    function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $('#Ecbooficinadep').append('<option value="' + item.Cod_Oficina_D + '">' + item.Nom_Oficina_D + '</option');
            $("#Ecbooficinadep").val(CodOficina);
            $('#Ecbooficinadep').change();
        });
    });
});
```

espero te sirva Bro... ReNiceCode..

Answer (score 0):

prueba esto, este codigo solo cargara el script una sola ves cuando el documento este listo

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    llenarcombos();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

La carga de datos automatica, lograras ejecutando una funcion dentro de otra

```js
function combo1(){
  $.ajax({
    success: function(r){
      var a=$("#combo1").val();
      combo2(a);
    }
  })
}
function combo2(a){
  $.ajax({
    success: function(r){
      var a=$("#combo2").val();
      combo3(a);
    }
  })
}
function combo3(a){
  $.ajax({
    success: function(r){

    }
  })
}
combo1();
```

```html
<select id="combo1">
  <option value="1" onlclick="combo1()">dep1</option>
  <option value="2" onlclick="combo1()">dep2</option>
  <option value="3" onlclick="combo1()">dep3</option>
</select>

<select id="combo2">
  <option value="21" onlclick="combo2()">of1</option>
  <option value="22" onlclick="combo2()">of2</option>
  <option value="23" onlclick="combo2()">of3</option>
</select>
<select id="combo3">
</select>
```

Pero para cada vez que cargues los datos, deberas remover los anteriores (`<option>`) del select que llenaras.